# Command Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma classe de queue no laravel 5.1 que faz uma inserção no mysql atraves de um csv, mas não consigo utilizar session nesta classe e nem mesmo pegar o id do usuario logado pelo oauth 2.

Como consigo fazer isso, pelo menos usar session. Dentro do metodo handler da classe command mando retonar `Session::get('id_logado')` ele me retorna null.

Comment: Comandos rodados na linha de comando não são capazes de capturar a sessão dos  navegadores. Creio que essa seja a confusão.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você adiciona jobs a uma fila de execução (queue), deve passar todos os dados requeridos. Por exemplo, se é um job para redimensionar o avatar de um usuário, a informação necessária é o id do usuário para que possa carregar o seu modelo. Como quando você está vendo na página de perfil de um usuário no navegador, passa as informações necessárias na requisição da URI (por exemplo, `usuários/ profile/{id}`).

Sessões não vão funcionar para tarefas da fila (queue jobs), porque as sessões são usadas ​​para definir estados a partir de solicitações do navegador, e os queue jobs são executados pelo sistema.

Então, continuando com exemplo de avatar do usuário. Você poderia passar o id do usuário para o job, ou passar o modelo de usuário inteiro, porém, caso job esteja atrasado o estado deste usuário pode ter mudado nesse meio tempo, então você estaria trabalhando com dados imprecisos.

Desta forma, para adicionar seu job à fila, usaria algo como:

```
Queue::push('AvatarProcessor', [Session::get('id_logado')]);
```

Quando o job iniciar, carregue o usuário do banco de dados e, em seguida, repasse-o para outras classes participantes do trabalho. Neste exemplo simulei o envio do id do usuário vindo da sessão como você deseja. Imaginando que o processo todo se inicia por uma interface de usuário em navegador.

A seguir um exemplo da classe de avatar recuperando a informação passada ao job.

```
class AvatarProcessor {

    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        $user_id = $data[0]; // o id do usuário está no primeiro índice do array

        $user = User::find($user_id); // peça para o modelo carregar os dados do usuário baseado em seu id

        if ($user == null)
        {
            // caso o usuário não exista, trate corretamente com avisos, quem sabe, por email ao administrados
        }

        // Execute a lógica de manipulação de imagem necessária, um exemplo simples seria o código a seguir
        (new ImageManipulator)->resizeAvatar($user);

        $user->save(); // salve as alterações

        $job->delete(); // exclua o job ao concluir
    }

}
```

Esta resposta foi baseada e auxiliada pela discussão em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548152/laravel-queues-persistent-variables-across-classes e pela documentação de queues do Laravel em http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues